# Simple folder password protection on windows server website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web-config

Is there an easy way to protect a directory or an entire website without root rights (with only FTP access) on a Windows server such as Linux with htaccess files?
Only one user needs to be able to log in.
Just to password protect a website I don't want to create a big login/logout page with database and ASP.NET Core Identity etc

Comment: Install an FTP server with only one user? You mention both a "website", "directory" and "FTP" so it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do here. What does "easy" mean?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to protect. If it's IIS then you can use Windows authentication.

Comment: I not need to protect FTP because it's already protected. I mean whole webseite or one dictionary (example.com or example.com/folder). It's from https://www.ionos.de/hosting/windows-hosting-tarife so i'm not sure if they use IIS

Comment: To create password-protect a directory or website on a Windows server using IIS and FTP access. Create a .htpasswd file with username-password pairs.Convert it to a format compatible with IIS (use tools or online converters). Upload the converted .htpasswd to your website directory using FTP.In IIS, go to the directory you want to protect. Enable "Basic Authentication" and disable other methods.Edit permissions to specify allowed users.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a user in windows.
[image]

[image]
2.Edit the directory folder permission, add that user.
[image]

[image]
3.Go to IIS, choose the level of the directory folder.(For only change your directory level settings). Click 'Authentication'.
[image]
4.Disable others, just enable 'basic authentication'. You may need to enable this feature in server role.
[image]

[image]
5.When you visit that directory. You could use this user to access.